# The return keyword acts strange

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working on a project in JS(Electron,Node.js)that needs to check if a key in the Windows registry is present.
Here is my code:

```
function IsSettedUp() {
regedit.list('HKCU\\SOFTWARE')
    .on('data', function (entry) {
        //Returns Keys
        console.log(entry.data.keys)

        //Checks if "WinXSoft" appears in the entry.data.keys array
        var key = $.inArray("WinXSoft", entry.data.keys)

        console.log(key)

        //Returns false if WinXSoft wasn't found
        if (key == -1) {

            return false
        }
        //Returns true if WinXSoft was found
        else {
            return true
        }
    })

    }
    //Should be true or false according to the WinXSoft key
    var z = IsSettedUp();
    console.log(z)
```

When I create the key and run the code,this is the output:

`console.log(entry.data.keys)` outputs `Array(42)`.(Expected)

`console.log(key)` ouputs  `13`(Expected)

`console.log(z)` outputs `undefined`(???,Should be true)

So yeah,do you guys know how I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Try to return value out of the `on` function

```
function IsSettedUp() {
     var result = false;
     regedit.list('HKCU\\SOFTWARE').on('data', function (entry) {
        //Returns Keys
        console.log(entry.data.keys)

        //Checks if "WinXSoft" appears in the entry.data.keys array
        var key = $.inArray("WinXSoft", entry.data.keys)

        console.log(key)

        //Returns false if WinXSoft wasn't found
        if (key == -1) {

            result = true;
        }
        //Returns true if WinXSoft was found
        else {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: This still returns undefined

Comment: @libert1quinten then you can init `result` with a default value and check your code logic

Comment: If I init "result" with the value of 1 it returns 1 but not true or false and I know for sure that my if/else statements are correct

Comment: There is still no *return* statement for the *IsSettedUp* function here. All the *return* statements are for the anonymous function that the *on* method takes.

Comment: @JohanWentholt thanks for your comment,and updated,it's my careless

Comment: @libert1quinten Updated my answer according to Johan's comment,you can check now

Comment: @Johan Wentholt I did try to return the result variable outside of the on method but it stills returns undefined.It's like that the result=false and the result = true don't have an effect on the result function.

Comment: @libert1quinten If you give the variable a default value like is done in the answer and return it outside of the function provided to the *on* method. It should always return `false` (default value in this answer) if the provided *on* function is called asynchronously. Since the method setting the return values is executed after the *IsSettedUp* function returns. For more info about asynchronous return values see the possible duplicate link under the answer. If the function provided to *on* is called synchronously this answer should resolve your issue.

Comment: Oops, I mean duplicate link under the **question**.

Answer (score 0):

that is because z is the value of `IsSettedUp` return , which is not there and hence undefined.

`true` is the return value for the callback provided to `on` function.

```js
function IsSettedUp() {
regedit.list('HKCU\\SOFTWARE')
    .on('data', function (entry) {
        //Returns Keys
        console.log(entry.data.keys)

        //Checks if "WinXSoft" appears in the entry.data.keys array
        var key = $.inArray("WinXSoft", entry.data.keys)

        console.log(key)

        //Returns false if WinXSoft wasn't found
        if (key == -1) {

            return false
        }
        //Returns true if WinXSoft was found
        else {
            return true
        }
    })
    return 'test' // ADD THIS RETURN
    }
    //Should be true or false according to the WinXSoft key
    var z = IsSettedUp();
    console.log(z)
```

try this edited code and see what the value of `z` comes out now, one line is added at the end of your function

Comment: This outputs "test" but I needs to ouput the result.

Answer (score 0):

True or false is returned for inside `function (entry) {`. Nothing is returned for outside `function IsSettedUp() {`, so return value is the default `undefined`.Formatting code could make function scope clear.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a solution for this problem so I decided to us another library that works fine now.